# runtime.WithForwardResponseOption not used when terminating from UnaryServerInterceptor

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-gateway

I've setup a grpc-gateway for a small testbed service and I have a UnaryServerInterceptor setup that checks authorization bearer tokens and validate against an SSO introspection URL.

```
func (im *Middleware) GRPCAuthenticator() grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
    return func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (resp interface{}, err error) {
        md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
        if !ok {
            return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unauthenticated, "metadata is not provided.")
        }

        values := md[Authorization]
        if len(values) == 0 {
            grpc.SetHeader(ctx, metadata.Pairs("x-http-code", "401"))
            return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unauthenticated, "authorization token is not provided.")
        }

        accessToken := values[0]
        res, err := im.client.Introspect(ctx, accessToken)
        if err != nil {
            grpc.SetHeader(ctx, metadata.Pairs("x-http-code", "401"))
            return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unauthenticated, err.Error())
        }

        if !res.Valid() {
            grpc.SetHeader(ctx, metadata.Pairs("x-http-code", "401"))
            return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unauthenticated, "invalid token: either expired or inactive.")
        }

        return handler(ctx, req)
    }
}
```

I also have a forwardResponseOption that I use for (hopefully) controlling returned errors and write it to http.ResponseWriter.

```
mux := runtime.NewServeMux(
    runtime.WithForwardResponseOption(httpResponseModifier),
)
.
.
.
func httpResponseModifier(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, p proto.Message) error {
    fmt.Println("httpResponseModifier!!!!!!!!!!")
    md, ok := runtime.ServerMetadataFromContext(ctx)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }

    // set http status code
    if vals := md.HeaderMD.Get("x-http-code"); len(vals) > 0 {
        code, err := strconv.Atoi(vals[0])
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // delete the headers to not expose any grpc-metadata in http response
        delete(md.HeaderMD, "x-http-code")
        delete(w.Header(), "Grpc-Metadata-X-Http-Code")
        w.WriteHeader(code)
    }

    return nil
}
```

when a token is good and valid and proceeds to the rpc method, it shows that it goes thru.
[image]

But when it's terminated at the interceptor, it doesn't.

Was forwardResponseOption not the one I'm looking for in capturing responses given by (and terminated at) a UnaryServerInterceptor?